# Preservation of symmetries of Tensors under lowering and raising indices

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, symmetry, tensor-calculus

How do you go about showing that symmetry properties of tensors are preserved during lowering and raising indices in a metric space? I know how do do it for individual tensors with given symmetries but was wondering if you could show it in general.

Answer (score 2):

If $$T^{ij} = T^{ji},$$
Then
$$T^{ij}g_{jk} = T^{ji}g_{jk}$$
$$T^{i}_{\ \ k} = T_{k}^{\ i} = (T^{i}_{\ \  k})^T$$
And
$$T^{i}_{\ k}g_{li} = T_{k}^{\ i}g_{li}$$
$$T_{lk} = T_{kl},$$

Comment: Is there a way you could generalize this to say that all symmetry properties of tensors are preserved regardless of their raised or lowered indices. for example the symmetries of the Riemann tensor.